# navigate bootstrap tab using jquery

Tags: jquery, tabs, navigation, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap Tabs. It works well.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="nav active" id="li_All"><a href="#All" data-toggle="tab">All Exchanges</a></li>
    <li class="nav" id="li_Beginner"><a href="#Beginner" data-toggle="tab">Beginner</a></li>        
    <li class="nav" id="li_AddExchange"><a href="#AddExchange" data-toggle="tab" style="color:black; font-weight:600" >ADD EXCHANGE</a></li>
</ul>
```

When the page opens, sometimes I would like to pass in a value for "tabActive" that is "AddExchange". How to I navigate/show the  #AddExchange tab instead of the default "#All" tab? Conceptually, I am trying to use window.location.replace below, but it is not working.

```
if (tabActive) {
    switch (tabActive) {
        case "Beginner":
            $("#li_All").removeClass("active");
            $("#li_Beginner").addClass("active");
            $("#li_AddExchange").removeClass("active");
            break;
        case "AddExchange":
            $("#li_All").removeClass("active");
            $("#li_Beginner").removeClass("active");
            $("#li_AddExchange").addClass("active");
            //location.href = "#AddExchange";
            window.location.replace("#AddExchange");
            break;
}
```

Comment: How do you *«pass in a value for "tabActive"»* ? Is it in the URL? Like www.example.com#AddExchange ?

Comment: Hi Louys, I am passing it via ViewBag (c#) to the razor page. I put the value into a hidden input file so I can grab the value via jQuery on the client side. I have other scenarios where I plan to pass it in via the URL. But regardless, it will be handled the same way (passed via ViewBag to razor page). - I actually got it working and posted my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the bootstrap method `.tab('show')` for this.

However you obtain your values for the variable `tabActive` is up to you. From there you can just do your if statement and use the method provided with the library, like so:

```
//We will assume tabActive = 'AddExchange' here
if (tabActive !== undefined){
   //This should open the #li_AddExchange tab on page load. 
   //IF that is actually the ID of your tabs' navigation
   $('#li_'+tabActive +' a').tab('show');
}
```

That should override your default `active` tab and select the dynamic one.
Here is a simple fiddle example using the method. Notice that the shown tab is not the default active one. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ommhdm4o/2/

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you set the tab you want selected based on your condition:

```
  //some conditions
  ViewBag.SelectedTab = "li_AddExchange";
```

Razor View, you grab the ViewBag value

```
 <input id="hiddenSelectedTab" type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.SelectedTab"/>
```

Using javascript you get the value that you just set to the hidden input and use it as a selector to the tab method.

```
<script>
    $().ready(function(){
       var selectedTab = $('#hiddenSelectedTab').val();
       $('#' + selectedTab + ' a:first').tab('show');
      });
</script>
```

To use tabs you need bootstrap javascript file imported after jquery.